# How get physical path from a static path (cdn) in c # net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I have my cdn pointing to a different path to my project

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdn\images"),
    RequestPath = "/cdn/images"
});
```

Can someone help me access that physical path from a controller?

If I use `HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` I get my project path, but not the cdn path

**The question is how to get the FilePRovider from your RequestPath**

Comment: why not declare the path in some common accessible place (e.g: exposed as const via a static class) so both your `UseStaticFiles` and your controller consume that common value.

Comment: for an infrastructure workaround, you can created a symbolic link to point to the actual physical folder from the relative folder from your application deployment path. this is not a portable solution though.

Comment: What do you mean by CDN path? :| And why don't you put the path inside appSettings?

Comment: I have the problem solved using a static variable as it says @KingKing, But I would like to know the FilePRovider from its RequestPath

Comment: I don't think you need to get the exact instance of `PhysicalFileProvider` as you set in the configuration code. It's just like an independent service (to read file) and should work fine as long as you have an input file path for it. So if you have a file path and want to read the file, just create a new instance of `PhysicalFileProvider` with that file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establishing the path in the configuration file solves the problem, we don't have to think about it anymore
Thank you all

Comment: So you solved the problem, but provided no specifics on how it was solved.  This makes your post useless to others.  Best to delete it.

Comment: The solution is the comment above.
Setting the value @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdn\images" in the appsettings.json solves that problem.